# Coverted exploded circle back to a circle - SketchUp

Tags: sketchup

Creating a circle lists the perimeter curve as a circle under entity info.

I would like to convert the exploded curve back to a circle.

I tried welding the same object but it is now listed as a curve rather than a circle.

Converting to a polygon does not help.

I need this to get hint of the center when hovering over a circle.

Answer (score 1):

No SketchUP knowledge here, but seemingly you have lost the centerpoint of a circle because you converted it to a geometrically same, but structurally different object type and cannot convert it back.

You maybe can use as a workaround the next trick which is actually made for 2D drawing programs. It works also in your case if SketchUP snaps to crossings, indicates them when drawing and allows rotating around symmetry points without specially setting the rotation center. These are true in 2D drawing programs like Inkscape or Illustrator.

[image]

In the leftmost image I have an ex-circle. It lost its centerpoint when a piece was sliced off.

To find the center there's drawn in the middle image two cord lines. Both lines start and end at the edge. They were easy to draw, because the line tool snaps to the edge.

In the right both cord lines got command "rotate 90 degrees". The centerpoint of the circle is the crossing of the lines.

Comment: I am not sure if this answers what the OP's needs but, nice technique. +1